# Task Schduler Log issues

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, task

I have been using task scheduler for scheduling batch jobs and I have enabled tasks history. However, I could not find any log file in `C:\Windows\Tasks`.

So where could I find the log files for that?

Answer (score 1):

Task scheduler has two logs: `Maintenance` and `Operational`, the files for it are at these locations:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Maintenance.evtx

%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx
```

but they are no text files, you can view the files in `Event Viewer` but they are already there under the path:

```
Application and Services Logs-Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
```

Most information is available right in the `Task Scheduler` UI under the `History` tab anyways.